# MC1314 voltage controlled attenuator circuit not working on breadboard - what did I do wrong?

Tags: audio, test

I have an old quadraphonic system with a problem that I've traced to what I think is an MC1314.  (That's not the question.)  So I ordered a replacement, popped in and it didn't solve the problem.  I decided to make a test circuit based on the data sheet (available here https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/570328/Motorola/MC1314P/1 on page 4 with notes on page 11.)  Here's the circuit I bread boarded:
[image: MC1314 Test Circuit]

The +18V was two 9V batteries in series.  Anyway, I plugged it in and blew the IC.  That leads me to suspect that 1) I screwed something up, or 2) The chip was bad, or 3) The chip actually wasn't an MC1314 or 4) The chip was an MC1314, but Motorola has recycled the number.  I haven't found any evidence of #4, seeing as how I ordered it from eBat #2 or #3 are also possible, and since I'm human, #1 is always a leading possibility.  Edit: What could have gone wrong?

Comment: A datasheet would help for this 4 channel VCA

Comment: @Duston:  You left several inputs and outputs disconnected.  It's possible it started oscillating and destroyed itself.  That's just guessing, though.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 The question includes a URL to the datasheet.

Comment: @JRE On Page 11 the notes say that "If xxx is unused, leave the pin open."  Also, 4 of the open pins are audio output.

Comment: The caps blew the input transistors

Comment: I see several notes indicating that unused analog pins should be "AC grounded."

Comment: @JRE I only see one mention of that, on Page 7 which is about the 1315 chip and not the 1314.

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering my own question because the issue is now moot.  I bought another MC1314, installed it in the stereo and it's working correctly, so a test circuit is no longer needed.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf/570328/Motorola/MC1314P/1. For the quad VCA obsolete chip.

Your schematic on the surface looks ok.

Did it overheat immediately? Polarity correct on Vcc, Gnd

https://4donline.ihs.com/images/VipMasterIC/IC/MOTO/MOTOS12755/MOTOS12755-1.pdf?hkey=D9A213CC6FEE7D103EF6B88F2AEB20B8
[enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bn5tB.png)

[image]

Beware the pins are shown upside down in the block diagram!

### ALSO your cap polarity is backwards

which shorts out the cap!! And may induce excessive DC bias current (?)

### why did it blow?

tl;dr = e-caps reversed, causing caps to conduct DC with low ESR, causing differential input Vbe of NPN’s to go negative with 0Vin and +ve emitters, causing Reb=~<10 ohms, causing avalanche punch-thru, causing Vce punchthru and unlimited current across conducting junctions, causing explosive results

- with >10W/sqmm  causing a crater in the epoxy but perhaps not sustained long enough to blow the e-caps which might have been a bigger explosion with toxic smoke , And;It enough  to exceed say a battery thermal runaway which would result in a bigger problem.
- most BJT’s have a -5V limit for Vbe.
- many e-caps can tolerate -10% of the forward rated voltage for a limited period.
- when you aren’t sure try to have current limiting for the size of the junction, BJT or IC or  PCB.
- use a passive RC filter or PTC oxide resistor for the safe limit might work if it heats up faster and rises in R faster than the junction,
- but not in this case.
- an active current limiter is pretty easy to setup for experimentation or use an LDO sized  appropriately, e.g. LM317

### Reading material

https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/AN1628-D.PDF

Comment: I'm certain I got the Vcc polarity correct.  You're right the capacitors are backward, I made a bad assumption.  I had the signal (1kHz, 200mV peak) applied.  I'm not sure how much (if any) DC is in that signal.

Comment: @Duston is the internal bias that might be damaged by reverse Vbe<-5V from 0Vdc input, but it wouldn’t get hot then you didn’t say if it did ...”blew. IC?” Symptoms??

Comment: "Blew IC" means a pop and smoke.

Comment: @Duston how entertaining, a negative resistance detonation with a crater of epoxy and rather toxic carcinogenic fumes.  Too bad. A PTC is good thing to experiment with.

Comment: Now that I look at the data sheet again, I see two schematics that include the capacitors on the inputs.  The sample circuit with the the whole chipset on Page 9 shows the - of the capacitors on the 1314 inputs (that's why I oriented them that way.) .  The test circuit on Page 4 shows them the other way around.  I'm pretty sure the stereo itself also has the - on the 1314 inputs.

Comment: I've ordered another (actually 5) chips.  When they arrive I'll revisit my breadboard and make it as much like the real thing as I can.  Stay tuned.

Comment: Guess what. I blew some SMD 10V caps accidentally shorting out a 5V on with square cut pigtails to the the fan grill to be used to charge my future wireless RH, Temp sensor and control a 100W 120Vac to dc 3 phase. Ridge controlled by an STM32 by remote alarm thresholds for my static attic vent to be active.  Doh, Senior’s moment.. even TI QA editor

Comment: So SAYALS had the parts and retrofit fix I go